# Parse a date from a string

Tags: java, string, date, extract

I have String like this:

```
String strDateTimeStamp = "2016-02-29 18:31:51";
```

Now I would like to extract it to get result in a below format:

```
String strYear = "2016";
String strMonth = "02";
String strDate = "29";
String strHour = "18";
String strMinute = "31";
String strSecond = "51";
```

Comment: You have to use SimpleDateFormat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This..

```
    String CurrentString = "2016-02-29 18:31:51";
    String[] separated = CurrentString.split(" ");
    String date = separated[0];
    String time = separated[1];
    String[] separated_date = date.split("-");
    String[] separated_time = time.split(":");
    String strYear = separated_date[0];
    String strMonth = separated_date[1];
    String strDate = separated_date[2];
    String strHour = separated_time[0];
    String strMinute = separated_time[1];
    String strSecond = separated_time[2];
```

Comment: Even though it provides the right answer. I do not think is the proper way of handling Dates. It should be handled with a DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with dates you should consider using Calendar :

```
    String strDateTimeStamp = "2016-02-29 18:31:51";
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTimeStamp);
    Calendar cal = new Calendar.Builder().setInstant(date).build();

    String strYear = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    // Calendar MONTH is starting from 0 we need to add 1
    String strMonth = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String strDate = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

    String strHour = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    String strMinute = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    String strSecond = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: Although Calendar.MONTH is zero based.

Answer (score 3):

All of the Answers using `java.util.Date` and `java.text.DateFormat`/`.SimpleDateFormat` are outmoded. Those old date-time classes are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. A vast improvement over the old date-time classes.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

First, replace the SPACE in the middle of your input string with a `T` to conform with the ISO 8601 standard. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "2016-02-29 18:31:51".replace( " " , "T" );
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime`. The “Local” means not associated with any time zone. So this is *not* an actual moment on the timeline. But apparently not an issue in the context of this Question.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

Now you can ask for your various pieces as needed by calling the various getter methods. These methods return an `int` [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which you can, of course, convert to String values.

- [`getYear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getYear--)
- [`getMonthValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getMonthValue--) (or [`getMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getMonth--) for [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum))
- [`getDayOfMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfMonth--) (and [`getDayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfWeek--) for [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum)
- [`getHour`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getHour--)
- `getMinute`
- `getSecond`
- [`getNano`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getNano--) (the fraction of a second)

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like this by splitting your `String`**

```
String[] splittedString = strDateTimeStamp.split("-|:|\\s");

String strYear = splittedString[0];
String strMonth = splittedString[1];
String strDate = splittedString[2];
String strHour = splittedString[3];
String strMinute = splittedString[4];
String strSecond = splittedString[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

First split string using `split(" ")` on the basis of space ..it will give you a array of string of length 2 . which contains `(2016-03-04)` and `(16:32:33)` . Then split both string againg using `split("-")` and `split(":")` reapectively . you will get your answer. Please try code at your own may better to you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **regex** with a pattern like **"[- :]"**

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strDateTimeStamp = "2016-02-29 18:31:51";
    String[] solution = strDateTimeStamp.split("[- :]");
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(solution[i]);
    }
}
```

this will generate an array with all the elements you need

Answer (score 0):

```
  String strDateTimeStamp = "2016-02-29 18:31:51";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTimeStamp);
Calendar cal = new Calendar.Builder().setInstant(date).build();

String strYear = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
// Calendar MONTH is starting from 0 we need to add 1 
String strMonth = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
String strDate = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

String strHour = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
String strMinute = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String strSecond = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```